# CDT (C development tools) in Android Studio

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I'm following some tutorials for OpenCV development on Android. Like a lot of Android documentation, it's written in terms of Eclipse, but I'm using Android Studio (2.1) All the references I can find to a CDT (C developer tools) for Android are in terms of Eclipse.

So my questions. Do I still need the CDT in Android Studio? If so, where can I find and how do I install them in Android Studio?